# Where to find gnutls-openssl for CentOS 7

Tags: centos-7, openssl, gnutls

I'm trying to compile a program from source on CentOS 7 (boinctui to be specific), but I'm getting the following error from `configure`:

`configure: error: Couldn't find gnutls-openssl library`

I can't work out where to get this library from. It's not listed as a package in `yum` - I've installed `openssl-devel` and `gnutls-devel` but that didn't fix it.

Various searches have turned up a blank. Can anyone help?

Comment: The file `boinctui-2.5.0/redhat/boinctui.spec` says : `BuildRequires: autoconf ncurses-devel expat-devel openssl-devel`

Comment: Aha. Obviously just running `autoconf` on its own isn't picking up the right spec. Any way I can force it?

Comment: The file `boinctui.spec` : `$ autoconf && ./configure  --without-gnutls && make` .... and when 'make' has finished : `# make install`

Comment: Thanks for walking me through it. Now I've seen where everything is I get what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora, CentOS : "boinctui" is built with no gnutls → See boinctui-2.5.0/redhat/boinctui.spec, which also includes the build text.

```
cd boinctui-2.5.0/
autoconf
./configure --without-gnutls
make
# make install
```

... Or you can build an rpm package from these files https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhx4ni44tvntnoa/boinctui-files.tar.gz?dl=0

```
rpmbuild -bb boinctui-2.5.0.spec
```

The result is `boinctui-2.5.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`. This package is also included in the dropbox link.

Install the package `# yum install ./boinctui-2.5.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`